# I got an error "[error] Element id=ui-id-7 not found" while running my script using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

[error] Element id=ui-id-7 not found- Selenium IDE -  I opened career builder site and started searching for QA Analyst jobs, but while trying to run, i got the error, can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You recorded your script wrong.
After your open url on selenium, add a function called `verifyTextPresent` and set a value `"QA Analyst jbos"`.

It'll work.

Comment: Thank You for your help, but where do I add that function? do I add it in the command line? if that is the case, I tried inserting a command and edit in the Table, but the tool does not let me edit?

Comment: You're welcome. So, you add a command. If you're using selenium-ide, there is a panel where your tests steps are being showed. Using your mouse, do a right click and choose the "Insert new command". After that, you can choose the function in Command field, above, in this case VerifyTextPresent. In target field you set "QA Analyst jobs". I hope have helped you. =)

Comment: Thank You for your help, I did exactly the same as you mentioned in your earlier comment and it worked

Comment: One more question for you?
If i get errors in my log while execution how do i debug them?

Comment: Hi. You're welcome. So, first of all you could select my answer as a correct answer. =). Second, I know selenium has a debug tool, but you just can add a breakpoint there. While you execute your process, selenium shows the information on tab "Messages". If think is the only way to show this messages to you in Selenium IDE. If you go more deep in this subject, you can convert / export this for WebDriver and do this analysis there. But, it's another thing to do. I hope have help you. =)

Comment: Thank You for your help, I am thinking of learning Selenium from Training institute, but I would like to know whether I need to have programming background(Java etc) inorder to learn RC and Web Driver. Kindly suggest me